# Local Properties of Connected Spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In Hatcher's discussion on covering spaces, he mentions "If $p: \tilde{X} \rightarrow X$ is a covering space, then the cardinality of the set $p^{-1}(x)$ is locally constant over $X$. Hence if $X$ is connected, this cardinality is constant as $x$ ranges over all of $X$. It is called the number of sheets of the covering.''

It is true that if $\mathscr P$ is a local property (i.e., true in arbitrarily small neighborhoods, i.e., given any point $x\in X$ and any open neighborhood $U$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $V\subseteq U$ and $\mathscr P$ holds in $V$) of a connected space $X$, then $\mathscr P$ is true globally? Is there a precise version of this statement?

Edit: It has been pointed out that my guess was not correct. Still, there are examples such that this holds. For instance, a connected & locally path connected space is path connected. Lukas also pointed out that any locally constant function on a connected space is constant. Are there more examples like these?

Comment: If something is true locally, then the set of points where it’s true is open. Since “card $p^{-1}(x)=n$” is open for each $n$, it follows that each of these sets is also closed. So if the space is connected, the cardinality is constant.

Comment: I think the formulation is unclear, maybe define a property $\mathcal{A}(x)$ or a collection of $\mathcal{A}_U$ for open sets $U$, but it is too vague to answer it. But anything that works with continuity will do by reasoning locally.

Comment: Any locally constant function on a connected space is constant. I think that's precisely what Hatcher uses here.

Answer (score 2):

No. The circle $S^1$ is connected and locally simply connected, but not globally simply connected.

Comment: +1. Another example is $\Bbb R$, which is locally compact but not compact.

Comment: Or $S^2$, which is locally (but not globally) homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The definition of local compactness does not seem to be the same as the "local" definition I gave.

Comment: @Zhuo. You may be right. But they are equivalent for Hausdorff spaces. Another issue is separability. The Long Segment  is connected and non-separable but is locally homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$. Perhaps you should see the book Counterexamples In Topology.